# Springboot swagger with JsonView

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui, json-view

It's possible to integrate the swagger with `@JsonView`? I have one model that I use the `@JsonView` to return only a few fields, but the *swagger-ui* shows the hole model.

This is my model:

```
public class Intimacao extends EntityBase {
    @Embedded
    @JsonView({View.Intimacao_Lista.class})
    private Devedor devedor;
    @Embedded
    private Sacador sacador;
    @Embedded
    private Apresentante apresentante;
    @Embedded
    private Titulo titulo;

}
```

This is my controller:

```
@GetMapping("/")
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMINISTRADOR') or hasRole('MOTOBOY')")
@JsonView({View.Intimacao_Lista.class})
public List<Intimacao> listar(Principal principal){
    System.out.println(principal.getName());
    return null;
}
```

This is the result in *swagger-ui*

```
[
  {
    "apresentante": {
      "documento": "string",
      "nome": "string"
    },
    "devedor": {
      "bairro": "string",
      "cep": "string",
      "cidade": "string",
      "complemento": "string",
      "documento": "string",
      "estado": "string",
      "logradouro": "string",
      "nome": "string",
      "numero": "string",
      "tipoLogradorouo": "string"
    },
    "id": 0,
    "sacador": {
      "chave": "string",
      "documento": "string",
      "especie": "string",
      "nome": "string"
    },
    "titulo": {
      "custas1": 0,
      "custas2": 0,
      "custas3": 0,
      "custas4": 0,
      "custas5": 0,
      "custas6": 0,
      "custas7": 0,
      "custas8": 0,
      "custas9": 0,
      "numero": "string",
      "vencimento": "string"
    }
  }
]
```

But if I `GET` my API only will return the `devedor` properties, because the `@JsonView`

Comment: Some code would help us a bit in understanding what you _have done/are trying to achieve_ better.

Comment: @lealceldeiro updated :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It's possible to integrate the swagger with `@JsonView`?

Yes <s>(partially)</s>.

After this [pull request](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/pull/2681) was merged you can use it for:

**Response Objects** (you got that part working).

```
@GetMapping("/")
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMINISTRADOR') or hasRole('MOTOBOY')")
@JsonView({View.Intimacao_Lista.class})
public List<Intimacao> listar(Principal principal){
    System.out.println(principal.getName());
    return null;
}
```

**RequestBody Objects** (<s>not yet, pull request on its way,</s> see [#2918](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/2918) and an example in [comment at #2079](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/pull/2681#issuecomment-406204200)). In your case:

```
@GetMapping("/")
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMINISTRADOR') or hasRole('MOTOBOY')")
@JsonView({View.Intimacao_Lista.class})
// replace `Views.Principal.class` for the proper value
public List<Intimacao> listar(@JsonView(Views.Principal.class) Principal principal){
    System.out.println(principal.getName());
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Hi I am using springfox-swagger2 version 2.9.2 (which is latest in Maven repository) but still it is not considering JsonView()

Comment: @YogeshHShenoy version 3.0.0 supports JsonView now.