# jackson reuse object ignoring some properties in rest request with java

Tags: java, json, jackson, json-view

Scenario: Im trying to reuse some properties of an existing dto to my Restful request.

Given:
com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.*; //v2.9.0

Im trying to do that:

```
class Parent {
 private String value;

 @JsonView(ChildView.Basic.class)
 private Child child;
}

class Child {
 @JsonView({ ChildView.Basic.class })
 private String basic;
 @JsonView({ ChildView.Full.class })
 private String full;

}

public class ChildView {
    public interface Basic {}
    public interface Full extends Basic {}
}
```

but when I access to my swagger:

```
{
  "value": "",
  "child": {
     "basic": "",
     "full": ""
  }
}
```

instead of

```
{
  "value": "",
  "child": {
     "basic": ""
  }
}
```

what im doing wrong ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Springboot swagger with JsonView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52895705/springboot-swagger-with-jsonview)

Comment: Sorry it doesnt work :S